# Increase SO_RSVBUF beyond 262142 bytes in linux

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

In my LAN only based application, increasing the transmit and receive buffers has a big impact on performance.

Under Linux I can increase the transmit and receive buffer to 262142 bytes.

Is it possible to get around this limit without making kernel changes? 
I'm using ubuntu server and if I compile a custom kernel I'm concerned I'll loose changes if there is an update applied. Can I set the limit somehow perhaps in a shell script when the machine starts?

EDIT: I forgot to point out that I'm using UDP.

Comment: cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `sysctl.conf(5)` for details on how to use the `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d/` configuration for changing `net.core.rmem_max` and `net.core.rmem_default`.

Comment: Thanks this has made a difference.  But, oddly enough using setsockopt I don't get what I ask for, I now get a larger buffer. Is that a bug?  I set it to 1048576 and then check it with getsockopt which returns that the buffer is now 2097150???

Comment: Heh, any luck with the huge socket buffer? I haven't heard of the kernel making such a gross difference in size; something small, to round to happy-alignment internal data structures would make sense, but doubling the size you asked for seems strange. :)

Comment: A slight increase in performance.  Once you get beyond a certain size, increasing it makes no real difference.

Comment: That makes sense; did you find out why the number from `getsockopt(2)` was twice the number you gave `setsockopt(2)`?

Comment: I found the answer in `tcp(7)`: _Note that TCP actually allocates twice the size of the buffer requested in the setsockopt(2) call, and so a succeeding getsockopt(2) call will not return the same size of buffer as requested in the setsockopt(2) call._